# Powershell: Use a string as multiple args

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, environment-variables, string

I have a string variable in PowerShell, `$t="foo bar"` and it should be passed as argument to command 'start-process'.

My 'start-process' needs multiple args which is "foo" and "bar" and not "foo bar", this won't work:
`start-process $t`

How to split that `$t` out so it will be `start-process foo bar`?

I can't split it manually coz 'start-process' receive arbitrary number of args.

Comment: [Split() - PowerShell - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html)

Comment: the command is actually start-process and it doesn't receive a string[]

Comment: @DavidPostill tks, i found it out, the first item after split is for -FilePath, others for -ArgumentList https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70479960/how-to-pass-an-array-to-the-arguments-in-start-process-in-powershell

Comment: @DavidPostill (and harrymc in the answer) are not talking about a string array.  They are talking about splitting a single string.  As in `start-process MyApp "string1;string2;string3;epsteindidntkillhimself"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will solve your problem as stated :

```
$split1,$split2 = $t.split()
Start-Process $split1 -ArgumentList $split2
```

This assumes that there are no special characters in the string,
or use the `strSeparator` argument of the
[Split function](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html).